# C++ array initialisation vs assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I'm new to C++ and have a question on arrays. I initialise a 2-D array as follows:

```
int myArray[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };
```

Is this technique for populating an array valid ONLY for initialisations? If so, why is this?

For example, if I then attempt the following, I get an error:

```
myArray[2][2] = { {2,4}, {6,8} };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the technique is only used for initialization. When you apply this to assignment, you will get an error. 
In

```
myArray[2][2] = { {2,4}, {6,8} };
```

myArray[2][2] is just the element of myArray, you can not assign it with that.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the array, you are creating a new memory area and setting the values in that memory area.

When assigning you have to set the values one by one, e.g. `myArray[1][0] = 6`

Answer (score -1):

Did you do

```
myArray[2][2] = { {2,4}, {6,8} };
```

or

```
int myArray[2][2] = { {2,4}, {6,8} };
```

??

if you tip

```
myArray[2][2] = { {2,4}, {6,8} };
```

you will get to the [2][2] case of your array